# Wrap columns in listView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a number of items I want to display in a listView. If the items exceed, say 8 items, then I want to overflow into a second column. Not sure what the best way to implement this is, tableview vs listview, etc. Currently, I have the items loaded into a hashset and displayed in a textview, but ideally i'd like all the items lined up in columns, I just don't want to gobble up view real-estate with a long scrollable list....

Example:
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5

would become:

Item 1      Item 4
Item 2      Item 5
Item 3      Item 6

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GridView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html